# how to embed latest blogger post to index.html?

Tags: html, indexing, blogs, blogger

As the title says, is it possible to embed the latest post of my blogger to the main index.html of the website?

The website main page is https://my-domain.com/index.html and the blog https://blog.my-domain.com.  I want to embed the latest blog post to specific place on my website's main page.  i.e. main page automatically updates when I post on my blogger.

Is this possible?

Comment: Definitely possible, but please post the code for your current attempt.

Comment: is that necessary? I'm new to coding, so i don't know what to do. But thank you for answering my question, I'll definitely find a way to do this. :)

Comment: anyone? Please?

Comment: This site is for help with code so we can't really do much without that. What you're asking for could be achieved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonp of your blog, create div like this for place of latest post `<div id="latest-post"></div>`

```
<script src='http://your-blog.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=latestPost' async='async'></script>
<script>
  function latestPost(json) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry;
    for(var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
      var link, title = entry[i].title.$t;
      for(var j = 0; j < entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if(entry[i].link[j].rel === "alternate") {
          link = entry[i].link[j].href;
        }
        document.getElementById("latest-post").innerHTML += "<a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a>";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)s - this would simply embed the page contents in another page. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="800" height="800" title="Embed google.com"></iframe>
```

However, iframes present big security risks (for example, cross-site scripting) - [avoidable](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) but a better approach would be something like Fajar recommends (i.e grab the content from the Blogger API, decode the JSON and set your content to the values downloaded).

In future, when you ask questions on Stack Overflow, include the code that you've already tried to get you to the solution. If you don't know how to do something, research the subject and use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) or similar to prototype things.